# Masm error variable must be declared in pass one

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm

When I try to compile masm msdos 1.25 program then it gives following error.

```
var: EQU 1
------some code here-------
IF var
------some code here-------
ENDIF
------remaining code-------
```

Error: var must be declared
in pass 1

Comment: There shouldn't be any `:` after the symbol name when you define something using `EQU`.

Comment: But there is the same coding as i gave. it's syntax is similar like i have given.it is.                     var:    EQU     1

Comment: Please refer: https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/master/v1.25/source/IO.ASM

Comment: The source file you linked to is meant to be assembled with the SCP assembler, not with MASM.